# CSS Animation not playing

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to add a slide up from the bottom CSS3 Animation to the `<main>` element in this site, but the animation is not playing / taking place.

Any idea why?

Here is the link to the page where it is not happening: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/animate/new.html

And here is the CSS for the animation:

```
.animated{
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
   -moz-animation-duration:1s;
   -ms-animation-duration:1s;
    -o-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
}
    60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
}
80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounceInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(2000px);
}

60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
}

80% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
}

100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateY(2000px);
}

60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
}

80% {
    -o-transform: translateY(10px);
}

100% {
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes bounceInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(2000px);
}

60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
}

80% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
}

100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.bounceInUp {
-webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
-moz-animation-name: bounceInUp;
-o-animation-name: bounceInUp;
animation-name: bounceInUp;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, just a couple of notes: **#1** You don't need the `-ms-` prefix for animation. IE9 does not support animations at all and IE10 supports them unprefixed. The `-ms-` prefix was only needed for the *early* IE10 previews, but later previews and the final IE10 support unprefixed animations. **#2** Why not use the shorthand and set the animation on one and the same class instead of breaking it over two classes of the same element? Also, could you make a reduced test case?

Comment: @Ana +1 for [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/)

Comment: @Ana Both valid points. Thank you. It works fine when I try it in JS Fiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/5hshn/2/ , but not when I try it in my full implementation.

Comment: When I inspect it using Developer Tools, I don't see any of the styles you have in `animate.css` being applied. Only those you have between the `<style>` tags (so obviously it works if I add the styles from `animate.css` there). Can't figure out why, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @Ana Yes, I noticed that. Any idea why the animate.css styles are not being applied? Should I just move all the animation styles inline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your HTML code, you mistyped here:

```
<link rel="stylsheet" href="animate.css" type="text/css">
```

It's `"stylesheet"` !

Comment: Wow, I assumed it was a spelling error, but I could not find it. Thank you for pointing it out.